# 2 Maybe queries in ROOM+RXJAVA

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I use ROOM + RXJAVA for SQLITE database in ANDROID application.

I have a problem. I need to insert a new record, but before that make a query for more information.

I use Maybe, Single and Completable.

I need to do the following:

1 query. Need to find out the ID of the cow:

```
@Query("SELECT " + COW_COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_COW
        + " WHERE " + COW_COLUMN_RFID + " = :rfid ")
Maybe<Integer> getIdCowByRFID(String rfid);
```

2 query. I need to create a weighting and add the resulting cow ID to it

```
@Insert
Maybe<Long> insert(WeightingDbEntity weighting);
```

How to do it correctly? Making an asynchronous query nested in another asynchronous query is not entirely correct. Tell me please.

If you make synchronous query, then there are no problems, since the result of 1 query is already available, if necessary, execute 2 query. In this case, do I need to add synchronous query (allowMainThreadQueries) to the ROOM? Or should I do it differently? How can 2 Maybe queries be combined into one and executed in transaction mode (@Transaction)?

I read here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction

But this example is about synchronous queries. And how to do it correctly with Maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `@Dao` annotated `abstract class` rather than an `interface` (as the latter does not allow methods with a body).

If you then use the `@Query("")` along with the `@Transaction` annotations to precede the method that has the body which can invoke the previously defined methods.

- The `@Query` with an empty query fools (if that is the correct word) Room into thinking that the database is being accessed and thus wraps the method within a transaction.

So if `insert` and `getIdCowByRFID` are in the same abstract class (simplifies matters) then you could have something along the lines of (noting that I've never used RXJava):-

```
@Query("")
@Transaction
Maybe<Long> doBoth(String rfid, WeightingDbEntity w) {
    Maybe<Integer> id = getIdCowByRFID;
    .... do whatever needs to be done/checked
    return insert(w);
}
```

The following is a screen shot showing the above technique with the `@Dao` annotated class, the `@Database` abstract class which includes the method to retrieve the `@Dao` class (so that the compile will check the methods). Albeit that the underlying `@Entity` annotated class is different:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did the right thing (I hope I understood MikeT correctly)

This is my DAO:

```
@Insert
public abstract Maybe<Long> insert(WeightingDbEntity weighting);

@Query("SELECT MAX(" + WEIGHTING_COLUMN_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_WEIGHTING
        + " WHERE " + WEIGHTING_COLUMN_COW_ID + " = :id")
public abstract Maybe<Integer> getMaxIdFromWeightingByCowId(int id);

@Transaction
public Maybe<Long> addWeighting(int idCow, String date, float weight, float weightGain, String description){

    getMaxIdFromWeightingByCowId(idCow).subscribe(new MaybeObserver<>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Integer idCow) {
            WeightingDbEntity weightingDbEntity = new WeightingDbEntity(idCow, weight, weightGain, date, description);
            insert(weightingDbEntity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
}
```

Maybe it's better this way:

```
  @Insert
public abstract Long insertSync(WeightingDbEntity weighting);

@Query("SELECT MAX(" + WEIGHTING_COLUMN_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_WEIGHTING
        + " WHERE " + WEIGHTING_COLUMN_COW_ID + " = :id")
public abstract int getMaxIdFromWeightingByCowId(int id);

@Transaction
public Long addWeighting(int idCow, String date, float weight, float weightGain, String description){

    long idCow = getMaxIdFromWeightingByCowId(idCow);

    // Here will be check for  idCow

    WeightingDbEntity weightingDbEntity = new WeightingDbEntity(idCow, weight, weightGain, date, description);
    insert(weightingDbEntity);
}
```

Or if I want the result in another thread

```
   @Query("SELECT MAX(" + WEIGHTING_COLUMN_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_WEIGHTING
        + " WHERE " + WEIGHTING_COLUMN_COW_ID + " = :id")
public abstract int getMaxIdFromWeightingByCowIdSync(int id);

@Query("SELECT " + WEIGHTING_COLUMN_NUM + " FROM " + TABLE_WEIGHTING
        + " WHERE " + WEIGHTING_COLUMN_ID + " = :id")
public abstract int getNumWeightingByIdSync(int id);

@Insert
public abstract Maybe<Long> insert(WeightingDbEntity weighting);

@Transaction
public Maybe<Long> addWeighting(int idCow, String date, float weight, float weightGain){

    int maxIdWeighting = getMaxIdFromWeightingByCowIdSync(idCow);
    if (maxIdWeighting > 0) {
        int num = getNumWeightingByIdSync(maxIdWeighting);
        if (num > 0) {
            return insert(new WeightingDbEntity(num + 1, idCow, weight, weightGain, maxIdWeighting, date));
        }
    }

    return Maybe.empty();
}
```

Comment: Before `@Transaction` or between `@Transaction` and the function `addWeighting`  add an `@Query("")`. Otherwise (I believe) the function is not wrapped with a transaction. That is the `@Query("")` is what, (I believe), allows the function to be wrapped within a single transaction otherwise the functions that access the db will each be a single transaction (again I believe, used to be the case).